# HIee, I'm trying to align the list component below the slider box

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fix the list component below the slider but it's not working, there is too much spacing in whole and it's pushing the below adjusting tabs to the bottom which is not visible on the screen. I am using expo to run it, but I'm not sure how to fix the problem here

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  SafeAreaView,
} from 'react-native';
import { getPopularMovies, getUpcomingMovies } from '../services/services';
import { SliderBox } from 'react-native-image-slider-box';
import List from '../components/List';

const dimension = Dimensions.get('screen');
const Home = () => {
  const [movieImages, setMovieImages] = useState([]);
  const [popularMovies, setPopularMovies] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUpcomingMovies()
      .then((movies) => {
        const movieImagesArray = movies.map(
          (movie) => 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + movie.poster_path
        );
        setMovieImages(movieImagesArray);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err);
      });

    getPopularMovies()
      .then((movies) => {
        setPopularMovies[movies];
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.sliderContainer}>
        <SliderBox
          images={movieImages}
          dotStyle={styles.sliderStyle}
          autoplay={true}
          circleLoop={true}
        />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.listContainer}>
        <List title="My List Co title" content={popularMovies} />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  sliderContainer: {
    paddingTop: 20,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  sliderStyle: {
    height: 200,
  },
  // listContainer: {
  //   marginTop: 20,
  //   paddingHorizontal: 10,
  // },
});

export default Home;
```

the top one is the list page and the bottom will be the home page that I am trying to add

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  SafeAreaView,
} from 'react-native';
import { getPopularMovies, getUpcomingMovies } from '../services/services';
import { SliderBox } from 'react-native-image-slider-box';
import List from '../components/List';

const dimension = Dimensions.get('screen');
const Home = () => {
  const [movieImages, setMovieImages] = useState([]);
  const [popularMovies, setPopularMovies] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    getUpcomingMovies()
      .then((movies) => {
        const movieImagesArray = movies.map(
          (movie) => 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + movie.poster_path
        );
        setMovieImages(movieImagesArray);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err);
      });

    getPopularMovies()
      .then((movies) => {
        setPopularMovies[movies];
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setError(err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.sliderContainer}>
        <SliderBox
          images={movieImages}
          dotStyle={styles.sliderStyle}
          autoplay={true}
          circleLoop={true}
        />
      </View>

      <View style={styles.listContainer}>
        <List title="My List Co title" content={popularMovies} />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  sliderContainer: {
    paddingTop: 20,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  sliderStyle: {
    height: 200,
  },
  // listContainer: {
  //   marginTop: 20,
  //   paddingHorizontal: 10,
  // },
});

export default Home;
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPGHQ.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPGHQ.jpg)
```

and then this is the where I am at

[image]